# How do you use SystemsModelFeedbackConnect?

Tags: version-8, control-systems

I'm trying to grasp the new control system functions in Mathematica 8. I'd like to connect a controller model to a model of a plant to simulate the behavior of the system.

I define a simple servo model:

```
servo = StateSpaceModel[{x''[t] == u[t] - x'[t]}, {{x''[t], 0}}, {{u[t], 0}}, x[t], t]
```

where `x[t]` is the position of the servo and `u[t]` is the input (voltage).

and a simple PID controller:

```
pid = TransferFunctionModel[5 + 0.01*s - 0.00001/s, s]
```

Now I *assumed* that I could link the PID controller to the servo model using `SystemsModelFeedbackConnect`:

```
loop = SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[TransferFunctionModel[servo], pid]
```

But the system doesn't behave as I would have expected:

```
input = UnitStep[t - 1] - 0.5 UnitStep[t - 10];
output = OutputResponse[loop, input, t];
Plot[{input, output}, {t, 0, 30}]
```

[image: Plot]

There's a lot of overshoot because the PID is not optimized at all, but I would have expected that the P part of the controller would pull the output to the (target) input eventually. But it seems as if the P factor scales the input, rather than the error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to first do a series connection of the PID controler to the plant. This gives the open loop transfer function. Then do a unity feedback connect to close the loop, like this

```
plant = StateSpaceModel[{x''[t] == u[t] - x'[t]}, {{x''[t],0}}, {{u[t], 0}}, x[t], t];
kip = 5; ki = -0.00001; kid = 0.01;
pid = TransferFunctionModel[(kip*s + ki + kid*s^2)/s, s] ;
openLoop = SystemsModelSeriesConnect[TransferFunctionModel[plant], pid];
closedLoop = SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[openLoop];
input = UnitStep[t - 1] - 0.5 UnitStep[t - 10];
output = OutputResponse[closedLoop, input, t];
Plot[{input, output}, {t, 0, 30}]
```

[image]

fyi, here is a demo 
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SimulationOfFeedbackControlSystemWithControllerAndSecondOrde/

Comment: I'd like to point out that @Nasser's demonstration cited above includes the nicest technique for object-oriented programming in Mathematica that I have seen.